# jQuery append() with attribute ng-model not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to append new HTML element with a ng-model attribute to a p tag when user performs a particular action, but the ng model is not working.
This is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


      <style>
          p{
              height: 600px;
              width: 600px;
              font-size:17px;  
          }



      </style>

    </head>
    <body>



           <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="editor">
            <label for="kys_font_size"> font size:</label>

            <select ng-model="kys_selected_font" id="fontsize" name="kys_font_size" ng-options="page for page in FontSize(1, 150)" ng-change="changeFont()">
               </select>   


                <p contenteditable="true"  id="content"   >


                </p>

              <p>{{fonttext}}</p>
          </div>





         <p></p>

         <script>

           var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
             app.controller('editor',function($scope){

                 $scope.fonttext="hello";
                 $scope.FontSize = function(start, end) {
                                      var size = [];
                                       for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                                       size.push(i);
                                       }
                            return size;
                      };


                           $scope.changeFont = function(){
                               $("#content").append("<p size='3' ng-model='fonttext' id='one'> This is some text </p>");

                              $("#one").focus();
                           }

             });

         </script>
    </body>



</html>
```

How can I fix this? Would someone give an in-depth explanation on why ng-model doesn't work here?

Comment: Could you setup a plunkr?

Comment: @CarsonIp $apply() No ! can you please explain

Comment: @SatejS can i know how that will me help me out with this?

Comment: That will help people debug your solution by exactly knowing what's going wrong.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I don't know what you are trying to achieve here. But you need to `$compile` the appended element. You need to inject the `$compile` function first to the controller.

Secondly, `p` tag will not accept any `ng-model`. I changed it to an input and you can see the model value ('Hello') loading.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


  <style>
    p {
      height: 600px;
      width: 600px;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>



  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="editor">
    <label for="kys_font_size">font size:</label>

    <select ng-model="kys_selected_font" id="fontsize" name="kys_font_size" ng-options="page for page in FontSize(1, 150)" ng-change="changeFont()">
    </select>


    <p contenteditable="true" id="content">


    </p>

    <p>{{fonttext}}</p>
  </div>





  <p></p>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('editor', function($scope, $compile) {

      $scope.fonttext = "hello";
      $scope.FontSize = function(start, end) {
        var size = [];
        for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
          size.push(i);
        }
        return size;
      };


      $scope.changeFont = function() {
        $("#content").append($compile("<input size='3' ng-model='fonttext' id='one' /> This is some text")($scope));

        $("#one").focus();
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-model` is not working because `Angular` already read the HTML document and already placed the bindings and stuff, so we could say that `Angular` is not aware of the element you just inserted.

You should avoid mixing `Angular` and `DOM manipulation` (`jQuery` mostly) at first, until you get used to *Angular's way of working*.

Meanwhile try this:

```
<p contenteditable="true"  id="content">
   <!-- ng-repeat iterates over an angular array variable (within the $scope) and prints the HTML as many times as the number of entries in that array variable -->
   <p ng-repeat="p in appendedParagraphs" size='3' ng-model='fonttext' id='one'> {{p}} </p>
</p>
```

And in the `Angular Controller` something like:

```
$scope.changeFont = function () {
    if('undefined' === typeof $scope.appendedParagraphs){
        $scope.appendedParagraphs = [];
    }
    $scope.appendedParagraphs.push('whatever you want to append every time'); // in angular appends, and DOM manipulation stuff is not doing directly, you just change the model (arrays, objects, variables...) and the template reacts over it and changes itself
    $("#one").focus();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou but i want append not hide. with a ng-model. is there a way i can do it?

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by append? ng-if does not hide/show but append/unappend an html element.

Comment: I did some changes to meet the *append* behavior in an Angular way without the need of `$compile`. But I repeat, you should try to **avoid** *DOM manipulation* (append, acting over jquery event handlers, etc) until you understand and get used to Angular and its workflow.